# Why is my Output 0?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

```
def russian (a,b):
    x=a
    y=b
    z=0
    while x>0:
        if x % 2 == 1: z=z+y
        y= y *2
        x= x/2
        return z
print russian(24,16)
```

This function uses the russian peasant algorithm to multiply two numbers together. I am expecting to see `384` as my output but I get `0` instead. What am I doing wrong? I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Is that return statement in the correct place? Consider looking at your indentation carefully

Comment: **indentation is important**

Answer (score 1):

You are computing the z value only once and then immediately return it inside the `while` loop. 
Lose one level of indentation for `return z`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `return z` is inside of the while statement making the function end and return `0` on the first iteration and `z` is never changed because `24 % 2 = 0` not `1`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Silly mistake on my art (clearly new to this).